# undefined referance to LibSerial

Tags: c++, g++, serial-port, posix, linker-errors

So i'm writing a serial transmision program, and have just changed over to using C++, it been a while since I used C++ 
(I've been working with C recently, and before that java)

Now I need to use LibSerial,
(it seems much simpler to use than C's termios)

my code is:

```
//gen1.cpp
#include "string2num.h" // a custom header
#include <iostream>
#include <SerialStream.h>
using namespace LibSerial;
//using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
        if (argc<2)
        {
                std::cout<<argv[0]<<"requires the device name eg \"dev/tty0\" as a parameter\nterminating.\n";
                return 1;
        }    
        SerialStream theSerialStream(argv[1]); //open the device
        return 0;
}
```

When I compile the output:

```
g++ -Wall -o gen1 gen1.cpp string2num.o
/tmp/cchPBWgx.o: In function `main':
gen1.cpp:(.text+0x121): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::SerialStream(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
/tmp/cchPBWgx.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE[vtable for LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf]+0x24): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::showmanyc()'
/tmp/cchPBWgx.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE[vtable for LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf]+0x28): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::xsgetn(char*, int)'
/tmp/cchPBWgx.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE[vtable for LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf]+0x2c): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::underflow()'
/tmp/cchPBWgx.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE[vtable for LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf]+0x34): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::pbackfail(int)'
/tmp/cchPBWgx.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE[vtable for LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf]+0x38): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::xsputn(char const*, int)'
/tmp/cchPBWgx.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE[vtable for LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf]+0x3c): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::overflow(int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [gen1] Error 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the linker complaining that it cannot find the functions referenced by the libserial header file.

If I look on my Linux system to see how the shared library is called:

```
$ dpkg -L libserial0
...
/usr/lib/libserial.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/libserial.so.0
```

On my system this implies I would add `-lserial` as a g++ option (aka link with libserial.so) this would turn your compilation command into

```
g++ -Wall -lserial -o gen1 gen1.cpp string2num.o
```

Answer (score 2):

Including the header file is not enough - you also need to link with the library that implements SerialStream. Assuming it is a static library called serstream.a (it is almost certainly actually called something else):

```
g++ -Wall -o gen1 gen1.cpp string2num.o serstream.a
```

Answer (score 1):

old thread, but i still use Libserial. here the completed answer 
My working setup.

Ubuntu 18.04
g++ 7.3.0

1) Install package for libserial

```
apt install libserial-dev
```

2) check for your headers(.h) and .so files

```
dpkg -l libserial0
dpkg -l libserial-dev
```

the first command give you the directory of shared library and the second gives you the headers location.

3) Your code.

I have to change a little your code, first i delete the custom header and modifing the constuctor call to this.

```
SerialStream theSerialStream;
```

4) compile with g++

Here my compiling command

```
g++ -o test -I/usr/include test.cpp -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lserial -lpthread
```

check for the -lpthread linking option, beacuse Libserial uses mutex.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu/Debian make sure you have to libserial-dev package installed and use the '-lserial' flag for gcc.